# Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/RaisedButton' in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the error

Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/RaisedButton' in 'C:\wamp64\www\multi-step-form\src\components'

I have installed @material-ui/core

My imports in this file are:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import RaisedButton from '@material-ui/core/RaisedButton';
```

and the dependencies in package.json looks like:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
  },
```

Can somebody check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `RaisedButton` button component in Material-UI. Instead just import [Button](https://material-ui.com/api/button/) and use the prop `variant` of value `contained` to have it raised. Don't use a variant of value `raised` as it's deprecated, use `contained`:

```
// ...
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

// ...

<Button variant="contained">
  Default
</Button>
```

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/w2kv82zn78) in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I am using stateful class component, how can I get const { classes } = props;?

Comment: @Ivana Just like you would access any other props in a class based component. `const { classes } = this.props;` or `const classes = this.props.classes`

Comment: I tried like that before few hours but I am getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'button' of undefined

Comment: You should please create a new question with a working example of the issue you are experiencing. You will get better support that way and will be easier to troubleshoot. It’s not clear how are you attempting to use the props in your application.